# Implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion, scala-2.10

```
class Foo

implicit def fromInt[A <% Int](x: A) = new Foo       // #1
implicit def fromString[A <% String](x: A) = new Foo // #2

0: Foo
```

gives

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: this.Foo
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method fromInt of type [A](x: A)(implicit evidence$1: A => Int)this.Foo
 and method fromString of type [A](x: A)(implicit evidence$2: A => String)this.Foo
 are possible conversion functions from Int(0) to this.Foo
0: Foo
^
```

I'm not sure I understand.

If I remove #2, it compiles.

If I remove #1, it fails to compile

```
error: No implicit view available from Int => String.
0: Foo
^
```

There is no ambiguity. `fromString` is *not* a conversion function from `Int` to `Foo`.

Why does the compiler claim that there is ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in 2.9.x and 2.10.x.

It is fixed in 2.11.2.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8857